# What is the translation for "hash" in french?

Tags: hash

I am doing a French presentation on basic cryptography, and the generation of random numbers. Most terms are easily translatable, but I can't seem to find a word for hash, as in cryptographic hashing, in french. The closest I can come up with is gâchis, which means "mess" or "failure.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about French. Given that it is trivially answered by checking the translation of the Wikipedia article, it would not be accepted on [french.se] (but non-trivial questions on technical terminology would be).

Answer (score 3):

In French, [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) translates to [*fonction de hachage cryptographique*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_de_hachage_cryptographique).